# jQuery \ Javascript - if statement does not evaluate correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I'm building a webpage with the following codes:

```
function change () 
{
    if($(this).hasClass("rosaLC"));
    {
        $(this).toggleClass('rosaLCb');
    }
    if ($(this).hasClass('rosaBC'));
    {
        $(this).toggleClass('rosaBCb'); 
    }
}
```

On the html, the buttons that trigger this function is the follow:

```
<div class="row">
    <article class="columnLeft">
        <div class=rosa>    
            <button onclick="playVid('crux');change.call(this)" class=rosaLC style="top:28px; left:75px;" ></button>
            <button onclick="playVid('gloria');change.call(this)" class=rosaBC style="top:460px; right:131px;"></button>
        </div>
    </article>
</div>
```

But, when the function `change()` is called, the if statement does not evaluate correctly, that is, when the `<button>` of class rosaLC is clicked, the function `change ()` add to it both classes rosaLCb and rosaBCb, and the original class rosaLC does not come toggled, the button still with the 3 classes:
    `<button onclick="playVid('crux');change.call(this)" class="rosaLC rosaLCb rosaBCb" style="top:20px; left:86px;"></button>`

What is wrong?

As a workaround I have split the function in two functions:

```
function change (thisObj) 
{
    $(thisObj).toggleClass('rosaLC rosaLCb');

}
function change1 (thisObj) 
{
    $(thisObj).toggleClass('rosaBC rosaBCb');
}
```

And change the html `button`:

```
<button onclick="playVid('gloria');change1(this)" class=rosaBC style="top:36px; right:58px;"></button>
<button onclick="playVid('crux');change(this)" class=rosaLC style="top:28px; left:75px;" ></button>
```

This is the only way that work as I wish, but I still not understanding what is wrong with the original code, mainly concerning the `if` statement.

Answer (score 1):

You are not defining what to toggle it with

Simply do this

```
function change () 
{
        $(this).toggleClass('rosaLC rosaLCb');
        $(this).toggleClass('rosaBC rosaBCb'); 
}
```

Also, pass the element object rather than using `this` since then it becomes reusable for purpose other than button click (some other event on another element)

```
function change (thisObj) 
{
        $(thisObj).toggleClass('rosaLC rosaLCb');
        $(thisObj).toggleClass('rosaBC rosaBCb'); 
}
```

and invoke it as

```
<button onclick="playVid('crux');change(this)" class=rosaLC style="top:28px; left:75px;" ></button>
```

Comment: `change.call(this)` will not expect the function to receive `this` explicitly. I wrongly posted an answer before seeing OP's code

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy hmm, i have made the change. I was wondering why you deleted yours.

Comment: @gurvinder372 I just try your solution, but still adding all the classes to whatever button I click.